# Creating a dynamic label with boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set my label size to be dynamic, however this current method is deprecated. I know that the correct method is:

```
boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:
```

This really doesn't do the trick for modifying the font size along with line break mode.

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize;
expectedLabelSize = [textLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Is there another method that should be used to change the attributes for my label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this..

```
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName,nil];
CGSize labelContraints              = CGSizeMake(width, 105.0);//Here I set maximum height as 105 for maximum of 5 lines.
NSStringDrawingContext *context     = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGRect labelRect                    = [str boundingRectWithSize:labelContraints
    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary 
context:context];
```

**Note:** It will working `IOS7+`